# Postgresql - Internal Array handling - array type or pointer type

Tags: postgresql, array

I have a question, about the internal handling of array columns in Postgres.
Does the engine handle it as a classical array with memory alloc or is it somehow a pointer list.

It would be interesting to know - I have a few questions to answer myself concerning performance... :)

Comment: Why not take a look at the [source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/array_8h_source.html)?  Or, possibly, you could ask this on a postgresql list as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are defined in [`src/includes/utils/array.h`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/array_8h_source.html) and [`src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/arrayfuncs_8c.html) and [the other `array*` files in `src/backend/utils/adt/`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/dir_ec2a658b940664c5751ddedb66fe6608.html).

An array is a `VARLENA` (see [`src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/varlena_8c_source.html)) which is a `palloc()`'d type, a scoped-storage wrapper around `malloc()`. Arrays are block-allocated data, not linked lists.

Comment: Good to have PostgreSQL expertise from specialists with a source code level understanding of RDBMS on DBA.SE, right? :)